# Why is this Makefile wrong? Linker fails only if preceded by compiler error

Tags: c, makefile, linker-errors, header-files

This is the example program to make it easier to explain. Have this 4 files, main.c, sum.c and header.h. and finally the Makefile.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = sum(a, b);
    
    printf("Sum: %i\n",c);

    return (0);
}
```

sum.c

```
#include "header.h"

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

header.h

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

Makefile

```
TEST_SRCS = *.c 
TEST_OBJS = $(TEST_SRCS:%.c=%.o)

%.o : %.c *.h
    gcc -c $^

assemble_test: $(TEST_OBJS);
    
test: assemble_test 
    gcc -o test *.o
    ./test

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o *.gch test
    @echo "Cleaned"
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Call test rule: make test > all ok.
- Introduce any error on purpose, example two commas:

```
printf("Sum: %i\n",,c);
```

- Call test rule: make test > Getting normal syntax error.
- Remove the error. Save file.
- Call test rule: make test > Getting linker error no matter what.

  ```
  gcc -o test *.o
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_main", referenced from:
       implicit entry/start for main executable
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make: *** [test] Error 1
  ```
- Use clean rule to start again every time.

Have this behaviuor for a while and i cant figure the problem. To be honest im new to Makefiles so i must be doing something very wrong.

About the test rule calling assemble_test. Its because part of a larger Makefile and i need diferent rules for diferent purposes to compile the objects, so dont mind.

Can you please help me understand what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's wrong to use wildcards for the object files.  Wildcards match files that *already exist* on the disk when `make` runs.  That doesn't help because obviously they won't match files that *do not yet exist*, and the entire point of your makefile is to create files that don't exist.

So this:

```
TEST_SRCS = *.c 
TEST_OBJS = $(TEST_SRCS:%.c=%.o)
```

leaves the value of `TEST_SRCS` the string `*.c` and the value of `TEST_OBJS` the string `*.o` (perhaps you were thinking that wildcards are expanded immediately, somehow?  No, that's not the case).

Then this line:

```
assemble_test: $(TEST_OBJS);
```

causes the target `assemble_test` to list `*.o` as a prerequisite: this will be expanded to all the object files that *already exist in the directory*.  But of course it won't expand to object files that you want make to create, but don't exist yet.

There are lots of other problems here: for example you don't want to compile `$^` because that expands to *all* the prerequisites but you only want to compile source files, not header files.  And the addition of `assemble_test` seems odd and makes things harder.

You probably want this, assuming you're using GNU make:

```
TEST_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c )
TEST_OBJS = $(TEST_SRCS:%.c=%.o)

%.o : %.c *.h
        gcc -c $<

test: $(TEST_OBJS)
        gcc -o $@ $^
        ./$@
```

By using the `wildcard` function you expand the value of the sources glob *first* before you replace the results with `.o`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251927/discussion-on-answer-by-madscientist-why-is-this-makefile-wrong-linker-fails-on); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Wildcard function solved the problem, have to learn so much...
- About the the .h as prerequisite for compiling, i need make to be aware of .h's posible modifications and if so, recompile the object files. That was working as intended.
- About calling assemble_test, the way you told me make wil complain about nothing to do, i want to be able to invoke test any number of times. Thank you so much for the solution!

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't add the header as a prerequisite.  I said you shouldn't _pass it as an argument to the compiler_.  If you use `gcc -c $^` then the `$^` expands to _all_ the prerequisites, so if you have `foo.c foo.h bar.h baz.h` as your prerequisites in make, you'll invoke the compiler using `gcc -c foo.c foo.h bar.h baz.h` which is wrong.  You want to use `$<` which expands to _only_ the first prerequisite, not all the prerequisites, so your compiler is invoked as `gcc -c foo.c` which is correct.

Comment: Regarding the `assemble_test`, if what you want to do is build the test one time and run it multiple times, you should do it like this: `test: $(TEST_OBJS) ; gcc -o $@ $^` which will _build_ the test program, then `run: test ; ./$<` which will _run_ the test program, then use `make run` to run it.  You can also add `.PHONY: run` to your makefile to be more clear.